# Using the Ratio Test for Series of Random Walks

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was watching the following video on Random Walks (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH2kATv49rc) where the following two series are shown (@14:07 and @15:05):

$$\text{Series 1:} \quad  \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{2n!}{i! \cdot i! \cdot (n-i)! \cdot (n-i)!}$$

$$ \text{Series 2:} \quad \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(2n)!}{i! \cdot i! \cdot j! \cdot j! \cdot (n-i-j)! \cdot (n-i-j)!}$$

**My Question:** According to the video, Series 1 diverges and Series 2 converges. I am trying to mathematically understand why this is the case (by myself).

My first instinct is to use the Ratio Test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) to check if these series are Convergent or Divergent. Here is my understanding of the Ratio Test:

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be an infinite series-  the Ratio Test states that if (note that $a_n$ is the $n^{th}$ term in the series and NOT the cumulative sum of the first $n$ terms) :

$$L = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|$$

- If $L < 1$, the series is Convergent.
- If $L > 1$ the series is Divergent.
- If $L = 1$, the test is inconclusive.

Now, I will try to apply the Ratio Test to both of these series.

**Series 1:**

- The $n^{th}$ term in this series is: $ \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2n} \frac{2n!}{n! \cdot n! \cdot (n-n)! \cdot (n-n)!}$
- The ${n-1}^{th}$ term in this series is: $ \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2n}  \frac{2n!}{(n-1)! \cdot (n-1)! \cdot (n-(n-1))! \cdot (n-(n-1))!}$
- If we take the ratio of the $n^{th}$ term and the ${n-1}^{th}$ term, we get:

$$L = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2n} \frac{2n!}{n! \cdot n! \cdot (n-n)! \cdot (n-n)!}}{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2n} \frac{2n!}{(n-1)! \cdot (n-1)! \cdot (n-(n-1))! \cdot (n-(n-1))!}} = \frac{1}{n^2} $$

- Now, if we take the Limit: $L = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$
- Since $ L<1$, Series 1 is Convergent (opposite result as indicated in video)

**Series 2:**

- I am not even sure how the Ratio Test can be applied here, because if $i=j=n$, then the term in the series $(n-i-j)!$ will become $(n-n-n)! = -n!$ and the factorial for a negative number is not defined.

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how can I apply the ratio test in these situations to check if Series 1 and Series 2 are Convergent or Divergent?**

Thanks!

Comment: As defined, "Series 1" and "Series 2" are finite sums (for a fixed $n$. Picking exactly the $n$.th term in the sum for the naive ordering makes no sense in order to decide something about the sum. Then going with $n$ to infinity..).

Comment: @dan_fulea: thank you for your reply! so the ratio test is not applicable for this question?

Comment: No (in the sense that it makes no sense to apply something in a framework that does not match). To have an example, consider the formula $$1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac 12n(n+1)\ .$$This formula holds and we are done. It is a finite sum. Now doing the same as in the question, we may look to the $n$'th term, which is $n$, to the previous one, which is $(n-1)$, compute some "quotient" (that makes no sense for the sum), then go with $n$ to infinity (for no reason) to conclude that we cannot conclude. Next example, $2+4+8+\dots + 2^n$. It is a finite sum, equal to $2^{n+1}-2$. "Quotient" is $2$. So what?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Is there a simpler way to show that series 1 is divergent and series 2 is convergent?

Comment: Please understand, there is no series involved, **as it is written** in the question. The video claims something different. For the first video series, consider the number $$p_n:=\sum_{0\le j\le n}\frac{(2n)!}{j!j!(n-j)!(n-j)!}$$and now consider the series:$$\sum_{n\ge 1}p_n\ .$$The $n$.th term of the series is $p_n$. (Connection with  the notation from the video my $p_n$ is their $p^{(n)}_{00}$.) If you want to use the ratio test, you need some formula for $p_{n+1}/p_n$. But this leads to nothing, since$$p_n\sim\frac 1n\ .$$